# Oracle APEX - ERR-1002 Unable to find item ID for item "ACTION"

Tags: oracle-apex

Using Oracle Apex version 23.1. I'm seeing this error everyday on the application error log. But I've had 0 user complaints about it, nor have I been able to re-create it. Which makes me believe it's not displaying the error message on the users page. I've searched all code on my login page, the application items/processes/computations, my authentication scheme. No where can I find a reference for an item named "ACTION". Does anyone know where I'm supposed to be looking for this error? [image: Application Error Log] [image: Debug Error]

Comment: Export the application as a single sql file, open it with a text editor and search (case insensitive) for the string "action" or ":action"

Comment: It can be tricky to find, particularly with a common word like 'ACTION'. Given the screenshot, you could probably isolate your search to your login page. It could be a 'page items to submit' attribute, a link target, or get/set a session state item.